# Excel VBA - Loop throught powerpoint shape and identify text line not in Excel range

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, automation, microsoft-powerpoint

I'm writing a macro to identify if the text lines in a PowerPoint shape are not present in an Excel range.

The idea in the last loop is that if the text line in the shape is not found in the Excel range, it is recorded. It is not working as the code is returning all lines in the shape, meaning that none was found, and if I add a `Not` condition it doesn't return any lines, even the ones that are not on the Excel range.

Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
Sub Updt_OrgChart_Test1()

Dim PPApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

Set PPApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")

PPApp.Visible = True


Set PPPres = PPApp.Presentations("presentation 2016.pptx")
Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(6)

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim teste_ws As Worksheet
Dim SDA_ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set teste_ws = wb.Sheets("Teste")
Set SDA_ws = wb.Sheets("FZ SW KRK SDA")

Dim shp As PowerPoint.Shape

Dim L5AndTeam As String
L5AndTeam = SDA_ws.Range("C3")
Dim Employee_Rng As Range
Set Employee_Rng = SDA_ws.Range(Range("B8"), Range("B8").End(xlDown))

For Each shp In PPSlide.Shapes
     On Error Resume Next
     If shp.TextFrame.HasText Then
       If shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Lines.Count > 2 Then
         If Left(shp.Name, 3) = "Rec" Then
            Dim prg As PowerPoint.TextRange
            For Each prg In shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs
                Dim nm As String
                nm = prg
                If Employee_Rng.Find(nm.Value) Is Nothing Then
                   MsgBox nm  <---- this is just a test, will add more code here
                End If
            Next prg
           End If
        End If
     End If
Next shp

End Sub
```

Comment: My feeling is that the `On Error Resume Next` you have there may be masking any errors that happen. Have you tried stepping through it and checking what values it finds in each iteration?

Comment: `Employee_Rng.Find(nm.Value)` `Paragraphs` method returns a `textrange` A quick doc check shows that there is no "value" property for a `textrange` object. Is ".value" valid? Resume-next would jump right over this. Also, you are presuming they are a full-text, no spaces etc match. Is this a valid assumption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be better off iterating through the Paragraphs or Lines collection of the shape's TextRange.  Simple example that assumes a selected text box:

```
Sub Thing()

Dim oSh As Shape
Dim x As Long

Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

If oSh.HasTextFrame Then
    With oSh.TextFrame.TextRange
        For x = 1 To .Paragraphs.Count
            Debug.Print .Paragraphs(x).Text
        Next
        For x = 1 To .Lines.Count
            Debug.Print .Lines(x).Text
        Next
    End With
End If

End Sub
```

Note that you can step through paragraphs or lines (paragraph = you've typed an ENTER at the end of it; line = you've typed a linebreak or the line's been broken by wordwrap)